# Pandas Upsampling Time Series Splitting Equally the values through the weeks starting on monday

Tags: python, pandas

I build my code studying this question: "[Divide total sum equally to higher sampled time periods when upsampling with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204504/divide-total-sum-equally-to-higher-sampled-time-periods-when-upsampling-with-pan)".

I am wondering if can be improved the code and if it is right.
It seems working properly, but always looking for room of improvement or if there is any flipside I am not aware in the process I implemented.

**Context**:

I have monthly data from Influencer Activities.
This data are Reach and Engagement.

**Goal**:

My Goal is to split equally this information through the weeks of the month.
Weeks starting on Monday

**Major Concerns**:

A month is on average composed by 4.34 weeks.

Am I missing some information using the following way when a week overlap between a month and another?

```
#Creating a min reproducible example
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

date_index = pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2020', 
                           end = '01/12/2022', 
                           freq = "MS", 
                           inclusive = "left")

np.random.seed(0)
reach = np.random.randint(1000,10000, len(date_index))
engagement = np.random.randint(100,1000, len(date_index))
reach_engagement = {"reach":reach, 
                    "engagement":engagement}

df = pd.DataFrame( data = reach_engagement,
              index = date_index)

#Resempling (the goal of the question)
df_resample = df.resample('W-MON').fillna("pad")
len(df_resample)
df_resample = df_resample/7
df_resample.round()
```

Output:

```
2020-01-06  533.0   136.0
2020-01-13  533.0   136.0
2020-01-20  533.0   136.0
2020-01-27  533.0   136.0
2020-02-03  609.0   28.0
...
2021-12-20  1228.0  129.0
2021-12-27  1228.0  129.0
2022-01-03  499.0   33.0
105 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: I understand that these data are artificial. Are you sure that `MS` (month-start) is accurate, i.e. the other columns correspond to months starting on the first and not months of consistent length? If so, your current method introduces error.

Comment: @Reinderien I think so, because on this open [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18f-MWfnMQLBYoQ7fy4UeHf1s4qWOZwVp?usp=sharing) that I used to craft the question and test it  works properly. Please let me know if you find any discrepancy between the question and the code, I will fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct use of `df.resample('W-MON')` neglects the fact that your `reach` and `engagement` are applied to months, which presumably all start on the first of the month and have variable length. `W-MON` is not variable-length. Instead you need to do something like:

- Upsample to days
- Divide by the number of days in the given month
- Only then, downsample to weeks

This could look like:

```py
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng

months = pd.date_range(
    start=date(2020, 1, 1), freq='MS', name='month_start',
    end=date(2023, 1, 1),
)

n = len(months) - 1
rand = default_rng(seed=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'reach': rand.integers(1_000, 10_000, n),
          'engagement': rand.integers(100, 1_000, n)},
    index=months[:-1])
df.loc[months[-1], :] = [np.nan, np.nan]  # for resampling

by_day = df.resample('D').ffill().iloc[:-1, :]
month_days = by_day.reach.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).transform('count')
by_day.reach /= month_days
by_day.engagement /= month_days

by_week = by_day.resample('W-MON').sum()
```

[image: generated dataframe]

[image: week-adjusted]

Comment: Yes Reach and Engagement are attribute to each month by the data source. I got your point and I 100% agree.